# Remove unwanted words from string

Tags: php

I have a csv file to read, but in one column there are some unwanted words.
It's easier to write the needed words into an whitelist array, than to make a blacklist.
This is what I tried, but i get an empty cell.
The following script is only used when the cell index is 5 (the column that I need to modify).

```
$whitelist[0] = "BLACK";
$whitelist[1] = "RED";
$whitelist[2] = "ON";
$whitelist[3] = "BLUE";
$whitelist[4] = "COLOR";
$whitelist[5] = "YELLOW";
$whitelist[6] = "GREEN";
$whitelist[7] = "CYAN";
$whitelist[8] = "MAGENTA";
foreach( $csv_line as $row ){
    $cell = explode(' ', $row[0]);
    foreach($cell as $b=>$v)
        if( !in_array($cell, $whitelist) )
            unset( $cell[$b] );
            $row[0] = implode(' ', $cell);
}  echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
```

Any tips will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Here's a tip: use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) and [fputcsv](http://php.net/fputcsv).

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. I am using fgetcsv. `$csv_line` contains a line from the csv file. Even without fgetcsv or fputcsv, the `$csv_line` could contain a delimited string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line
 `if( !in_array($cell, $whitelist) )`
to
 `if( !in_array($v, $whitelist) )`
you want to check if the value `$v` is not whitelisted, not the whole `$cell` array

Comment: @gion_13 thanks for your reply. but my cell is still empty and i don't know why...

Comment: it should work. try debugging your code with `var_dump` to check whether your cell isn't already empty.You could also echo something when the `if` statement is reached to check if not all of your cell words aren't whitelisted.

Comment: i want to check only the 5th column. now the entire row. would that be a problem?

Comment: it shouldn't break your code.But, if you only want to check the 5th column, don't waste your resources on useless iterations:don't check `foreach($cell as $b=>$v)`, but check only for `$cell[4]`

Comment: i checked the variables and at the second `foreach` $cell returns Array[0]=>... some letter, but only one letter. i guess it's form the start of each cell or word

Comment: i found another method:

          $csv_ex = explode(' ', $csv_line[5]);
          $nr_csv = count($csv_ex);
          echo $nr_csv;
         for($x=0; $x==$nr_csv; $x++){

                  $pass_key = array_search($csv_ex[$x], $whitelist);
                  echo "<td>".$whitelist[$pass_key]."</td>";

But it goes into an infinite loop.